# Where to read release notes for Xbox controller firmware?

Tags: controllers, xbox-series-x-series-s

Where can I read release notes or a changelog for Xbox controller firmware?

I searched online but only found release notes for Xbox system updates https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/help/hardware-network/settings-updates/whats-new-xbox-one-system-updates

Comment: I don't think there is any official sources for controller updates. The best I could find was an Xbox Wire post from September https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2021/09/08/xbox-controller-firmware-update-rolling-out-to-insiders-starting-today/